# Excel: filling a table based on trendline equation without creating a chart/trendline

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

Is it possible to generate a trendline equation without drawing a graph?

I have a column that is missing about 30 data points, I'd like to fill the blanks based on a trendline of the existing data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel's functions  **"FOR3ECAST"** or **"TREND"** (using array-formulae) will get you what you want **assuming the trend is linear**.

By futzing with the data, you may be able to get a  polynomial curve fitting .

This taken from Excel Help:

**FORECAST**

FORECAST(x,known_y's,known_x's)

*Calculates, or predicts, a future value by using existing values. The predicted value is a y-value for a given x-value. The known values are existing x-values and y-values, and the new value is predicted by using linear regression. You can use this function to predict future sales, inventory requirements, or consumer trends.*

---

**TREND**

TREND(known_y's,known_x's,new_x's,const)

*Returns values along a linear trend. Fits a straight line (using the method of least squares) to the arrays known_y's and known_x's. Returns the y-values along that line for **the array of new_x's that you specify.***

Comment: Any way to calculate the missing values if the trend is not linear?